# Kentico - Can a media library be used as a Form files folder?

Tags: forms, kentico

I have a form with an Upload file field on a Kentico 9 website. Form files are currently stored in the default folder (BizFormFiles). I would like to store those files in a place where I can easily manage and delete them on the CMS. Would it be possible to store them automatically in a media library folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I'm aware. It can't be configured this way. The only way to make this manageable via CMS interface is to develop a custom module with a custom interface.

Comment: I would say it is possible. I have created a new media library in my instance and then I have used that folder path as the custom form files folder. The form files are then placed inside this library folder in a <siteCodeName> subfolder. And then, I can also see the file in the Media library UI - just with the yellow exclamation mark that the files was not "imported" into the Kentico DB. The only downside I see here is multi-site environment. While the media library is assigned to a particular site, the form files from all sites will be stored in that media library folder.

Comment: Thanks, @jurajo! That's good to know! Could you post this as an answer then? I'll vote for it)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new media library in my instance and then I have used that folder path as the custom form files folder in the Settings.
The form files are then placed inside this library folder in a  subfolder. And then, I can also see the file in the Media library UI - just with the yellow exclamation mark that the files was not "imported" into the Kentico DB.

The only downside I see here is multi-site environment. While the media library is assigned to a particular site, the form files from all sites will be stored in that media library folder.